# Editing tables in ArcGIS for Desktop with Python Parser of Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, field-calculator, table

so I'm trying to edit a table so that the name column will not contain spaces. I just don't know how to write the Python script that should go with it.

[image]

This is what I have for the Python script now.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a complicated codeblock for this. The one-line expression is:

```
!NAME!.replace(" ", "_")
```

Comment: I get an error that says there was an unexpected statement when I do that though :(

Comment: Did you delete what you had in the codeblock? Are you sure you've got Python parser selected (it may default back to VBScript)? Other than that, I'll just say it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you did want to use the codeblock ([arcgis 10.0](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000004s000000)) you need to define a function and return a value.  Example:

```
def rename(field):
  if " " in field:
    return field.replace(" ", "_")
```

Then below the codeblock:

rename(!NAME!)

This assumes that the NAME field is a text value.